# Jquery certain radio buttons return true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to figure out why this code won't expose the proper `p` tag when the submit button is clicked.  The object is to tell a user if their answers pass or fail.

```
$('#screenfail').hide();
$('#screensuccess').hide();

$('#actiontime').click(function () {
    if ($("#quest11", "#quest21").is(':checked') == true) {
        $('#screensuccess').show(); 
    } else {
        $('#screenfail').show();
    }
});

<div>
    <p>Quest 1.</p>
    <input type="radio" name="clinic" id="quest11" value="1" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="clinic" id="quest12" value="0" />No

    <p>Quest 2.</p>
    <input type="radio" name="age" id="quest21" value="1" />Yes
    <input type="radio" name="age" id="quest22" value="0" />No

    <p id="screenfail">
        Thanks but no thanks.
    </p>

    <p id="screensuccess">
        You made it!
    </p>

    <p>
        <input id="actiontime" type="submit" value="Submit Me!" name="submit">
    </p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your check to:

```
if ($("#quest11").is(':checked') && $("#quest21").is(':checked')) {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P5esG/1/)**

Comment: likewise...mere seconds

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
if ($("#quest11:checked, #quest21:checked").length == 2) {
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/P5esG/2/)